# What does underscore at the end of the function mean in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I noticed some function names ending with `_` in Haskell (e.g. `mapM_`, `traverse_`).

What does it mean?

Comment: Do you mean like `traverse_`, `mapM_`, etc.?

Comment: It's briefly mentioned under "naming conventions" here:  http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html Essentially it's used to mean that the "result" of a monadic value/action is ignored, the action being used purely for its "side effects". (Quotes are because this is strictly true only for IO, where I think the distinction is easier to understand - for other, "pure" Monads/Applicatives, it's more of an analogy.)

Comment: @RobinZigmond I wouldn't call it an analogy, so much as a generalization. It means "for its Applicative effects", where for IO that effect is often called a side effect.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's just a naming convention in the Prelude. Generally, the functions without an underscore (e.g. `traverse`, `sequence`, `mapM`) return some meaningful 'aggregate' value, whereas the counterparts with an underscore (e.g. `traverse_`, `sequence_`, `mapM_`) return `()`. Usually you would use the first set of functions, but if you don't care about the return value then you would use the second set of functions. The reason for this is that these functions are usually monadic; if you use a function returning `()` in a monadic context but ignore the return value, GHC does not give a warning (since it will always return `()`), but GHC does warn you if the function does give a meaningful return value which you ignore. So e.g. `do { sequence [print 1,print 2,print 3]; putStrLn "ignoring prev value" }` will give a warning, but `do { sequence_ [print 1,print 2,print 3]; putStrLn "ignoring prev value" }` will not.

Comment: Returning `()` is also sometimes "easier". `traverse_`, for example, only requires a `Foldable` collection, because the collection does not need to be rebuilt in the new context, even though `traverse` requires `Traversable`.

Comment: It can also have a substantial performance impact. `traverse` has to hold on to the pieces it needs to build the result, while `traverse_` can just throw them away as it goes.